# How to make BottomNavigationView Horizontally Oriented Icon and Label?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-bottom-nav-view

I want to alight icon and label of `BottomNavigationView` align horizontally. Something like this
[image]

Default orientation is given as

[image]

Should I make custom layout for menu items or is there any simple way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [this library](https://github.com/ismaeldivita/chip-navigation-bar) to get bottom navigation bar with  chips component.

```
buildscript {
    ...
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        ...
    }
dependencies {
implementation 'com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation:chip-navigation-bar:1.0.0'
}
```